# How to change cursor for the whole document (not only within the body) via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In the way it's cross-browser, using JavaScript only.

Comment: Does `<head>...</head>` tag need to set cursor?

Comment: @S.Mark: The area of the `body` element on a page can be smaller than the viewport if there isn't that much content and nothing's been done to force it. I think that's what he's talking about (not that it's clear).

Comment: @S.Mark: As T.J. Crowder says.

Comment: As this is basically the same question as the one three hours ago, please specify what that solution is failing to do.

Comment: Frank, you can't blame S.Mark, though -- it's not like the question was, you know, thoroughly described. :-)

Comment: @Guffa: If you mean things with styleSheets[0].addRule and styleSheets[0].insertRule, well, I have no idea but that somehow hangs ie6 on my system.

Comment: I thought we can ignore IE 6 now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that the `body` element isn't filling the viewport because there isn't much content on the page (this is especially true on IE). You can force it to fill the viewport with CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

...which then ensures the cursor is a pointer anywhere in the viewport.

*Edit*: And having ensured that the `body` element fills the viewport, you can use the `style` object on the `document.body` to set the cursor from JavaScript. So to change it to a crosshair:

```
document.body.style.cursor = 'crosshair';
```

If you can't apply CSS at all in advance, this seems to work:

```
document.documentElement.style.height = "100%";
document.body.style.height = "100%";
document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

Comment: Yeah, I am now doing this way.